# Select all text in a NSTextField using Swift

Tags: swift, nstextfield

How can I programatically select all the text in a NSTextField using Swift?

For UITextField theres a method like

```
textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRangeFromPosition(...)
```

Comment: Do you want to get all the text from the field in code, or update the NSTextField so that it appears as if it is all selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in a playground:

```
import XCPlayground
import AppKit

let view = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))

XCPShowView("view", view)

let txtf = NSTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 50))

view.addSubview(txtf)

txtf.stringValue = "falling asleep at the keyboard..."

txtf.selectText(nil) // Ends editing and selects the entire contents of the text field

var txt = txtf.currentEditor() // returns an NSText

txt.selectedRange // --> (0,33)
```

Command-click on `selectedRange`, then on `NSText` (its return type), which will jump you to its Swiftened header where you can check out its rich functionality...

Answer (score 3):

Better solution:

```
import Cocoa

class TextFieldSubclass: NSTextField {
    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(theEvent)
        if let textEditor = currentEditor() {
            textEditor.selectAll(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Or for precise selection:

```
import Cocoa

class TextFieldSubclass: NSTextField {
    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(theEvent)
        if let textEditor = currentEditor() {
            textEditor.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(location, length)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Works for me:

```
import Cocoa

class TextFieldSubclass: NSTextField {
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let source = CGEventSourceCreate(CGEventSourceStateID.HIDSystemState)
        let tapLocation = CGEventTapLocation.CGHIDEventTap
        let cmdA = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, 0x00, true)
        CGEventSetFlags(cmdA, CGEventFlags.MaskCommand)
        CGEventPost(tapLocation, cmdA)
        return true
    }
}
```