# NSSearchField - How to select all text? (Swift/Storyboards on macOS)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

It seems everything online is mostly about iOS/UI controls, not macOS/Cocoa NS controls. Anyway, How does one make an NSSearchField select all text in the field programatically? I have tried multiple methods adapted from the iOS UISearchBar implementations, but none of them compiled or worked. I just want to, for instance, press a button and have it hilight the text that is inside the NSSearchField's text field. I can't seem to find a method within it that allows this to happen.

Thank you for your help/consideration!

Comment: NSSearchField inherits from NSTextField. You can check this post how to select all of the text in a textfield https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126273/select-all-text-in-a-nstextfield-using-swift

Comment: @AmirZ I cannot seem to work with an NSSearchField like I can a TextField. Can you please give an example of telling the SearchField to select all text? I tried variations of the examples in your link and could not get the right result.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in the given link in a clean environment or playground? 
specially the selectText(_:)  function which is the one that actually does the selecting and ends editing, as described in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399430-selecttext?language=swift

Comment: P.S the answer you are looking for is the one that is marked as correct answer, and you can simply replace the NSTextField With NSSearchField, the result will be the same.

Comment: Is the search field focused?

Answer (score 0):

All editing in `NSTextField` is handled by `NSText` (which inherits from `NSTextView`). So, to select the text in your search field, you need to set the selected range in field's current editor. This example highlights the whole text.

Objective-C:

```c
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, searchField.stringValue.length);
NSText *editor = [searchField currentEditor];
[editor setSelectedRange:range];
```

Swift

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: searchField.stringValue.length)
let editor = searchField.currentEditor()
editor?.selectedRange = range
```